# trouble returning datatable within a try statement

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable, streamreader

I have the following piece of code that I am using to try and rip a csv file and turn it into a datatable.  My problem is that the debugger never makes it to the return statement.  Everything is appending to the datatable correctly, so I know that part works.  Any idea's on what I can do to trouble shoot this further.  Also, if you know of a simpler way to turn a import a csv file to a datatable I'd be very interested in learning about it.

Thanks!

```
    Public Function loadCSVTableII() As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable("TableII")
    Dim line As String = String.Empty
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(pathTableTwo)

    Try
        While Not IsNothing(line)
            line = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim lineSep As String() = line.Split(New Char() {","c})

            If Not counter = 0 Then
                dt.Rows.Add(lineSep)
                counter += 1
            Else
                For Each value As String In lineSep
                    dt.Columns.Add(value)
                Next
                counter += 1
            End If
        End While

        'cursor never gets to this code block...
        Dim primarykey(0) As DataColumn
        primarykey(0) = dt.Columns("Ages")
        dt.PrimaryKey = primarykey

        Return dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Function
```

Update:  It is erroring out on this line in the code.

```
Dim lineSep As String() = line.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

It say that the Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.  What's weird though is that it works through the whole data table fine.  Could it be that the while loop is not terminating at the end of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `While` loop to handle the end of stream condition.  It's not very clear what the `IsNothing` function is doing in your code.

```
 While Not reader.EndOfStream
   line = reader.ReadLine
   '// Dim lineSep As String() = line.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

For your line split, in VB.Net, it's simple to just do this:

```
Dim lineSep As String() = line.Split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OLEDB provider for this.

```
string query = "SELECT Symbol, [Name of Company], FROM [just file name with extension]"; 
            string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + [csv file path without file name] + ";" + "Extended Properties=’text;HDR=YES;’";

            //create dataadapter object 
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connStr);

            // create table 
            DataTable dtSymbolDetails = new DataTable("ScriptDetails"); 
            dtSymbolDetails.Columns.Add("Symbol"); 
            dtSymbolDetails.Columns.Add("Name of Company");

            // fill the table with data using adapter 
            adapter.Fill(dtDetails);
```